# Kurdish Language Support on Google Play Books

Tags: right-to-left, google-play-books

Does Google Play Books support the Kurdish language for both content and user interface? Specifically, can I publish an e-book in Kurdish on the platform, considering its script is similar to Arabic and follows a right-to-left format, as in the case of Central Kurdish?

Despite searching the language policies, I couldn't find information on Google Play Books' support for Kurdish. Thus any help and clarifications will be greatly appreciated!

Regards, Nma Shawkat.